# Drawing spirograph with singular line

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am having issues animating said code. I am able to create the spirograph just fine but I would like to to edit this code to make it look as if it is being drawn instead of just instantly there if that makes sense. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

PS. this is for class though animation is not required I just would like to see how I would go about doing this

HTML

````
<head>

</head>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"
style="border:1px solid black;">

<script src="test.js"></script>

Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
<br>
<button onclick="draw(context)">Draw</button>
<button onclick="randoSpiro(context)">Random</button>
<button onlick="drawSpiro()">Draw Spiro</button>
<b>High = .01 </b> <input id="resolution" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" onchange="draw(context)"><b> 1 = Low</b>
<br>
R<input id="R" value="86" type="number" onchange="draw(context)"></td>
<br>
r<input id="r" value="75" type="number" onchange="draw(context)"></td>
<br>
O<input id="O" value="30" type="number" onchange="draw(context)"></td>
<br>
T-Ratio<input id="t" value="9" type="number" step="0.1" onchange="draw(context)">
<br>



</body>
</html>


var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");



function draw(position){
  let R = parseInt(document.getElementById("R").value);
  let r = parseInt(document.getElementById("r").value);
  let O = parseInt(document.getElementById("O").value);
  let t = parseFloat(document.getElementById("t").value);
  let i = parseFloat(document.getElementById("resolution").value / 100);

  spiro(R,r,O,t,i,position);
}
/////////Randomly creates variables for spirograph//////////
function randoSpiro(position){

  let R = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(200))
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(140))
  let O = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(200))
  let t = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) / 10) + 0.1
  let i = parseFloat(document.getElementById("resolution").value / 100);

  spiro(R,r,O,t,i,position);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////Creates Spirograph//////////////////////////
function spiro(R,r,O,tRatio,resolution,position){

var cx = canvas.width / 2 ;
var cy = canvas.height / 2 ;
position.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


position.moveTo(cx, cy); 
position.beginPath();

    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i+= resolution) {

        let t  = tRatio * i;
        let x = cx + ((R+r)*Math.cos(t) - (r+O)*Math.cos(((R+r)/r)*t));
                let y = cy - ((R+r)*Math.sin(t) - (r+O)*Math.sin(((R+r)/r)*t));

     position.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    position.strokeStyle = "#000";
    position.stroke();

}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Draw spirograph
function drawSpiro(R,r,O,tRatio,i,position){

  var cx = canvas.width / 2 ;
  var cy = canvas.height / 2 ;
  position.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  position.moveTo(cx, cy); 
  position.beginPath();

  for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {

          let t  = tRatio * i;
          let x = cx + ((R+r)*Math.cos(t) - (r+O)*Math.cos(((R+r)/r)*t));
          let y = cy - ((R+r)*Math.sin(t) - (r+O)*Math.sin(((R+r)/r)*t));

       position.lineTo(x, y);
      position.strokeStyle = "#000";
      position.stroke();
    }
  }```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get some animation into your coode you will have to refactor your code a little bit:

- Create a function that draws only one line segment of your loop. This means, begin a new path and stroke every segment
- call requestAnimationFrame repeatedly instead of your loop, stop at your iteration count
- Take care if another line drawing started! If so, stop calling requestAnimationFrame

Here a simple implenentation. Play around a little bit with the parameters and maybe add colors. Have fun!

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ident = 0;


function draw(position) {
  let R = parseInt(document.getElementById("R").value);
  let r = parseInt(document.getElementById("r").value);
  let O = parseInt(document.getElementById("O").value);
  let t = parseFloat(document.getElementById("t").value);
  let i = parseFloat(document.getElementById("resolution").value / 100);

  spiro(R, r, O, t, i, position);
}
/////////Randomly creates variables for spirograph//////////
function randoSpiro(position) {

  let R = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(200))
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(140))
  let O = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(200))
  let t = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) / 10) + 0.1
  let i = parseFloat(document.getElementById("resolution").value / 100);

  spiro(R, r, O, t, i, position);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////Creates Spirograph//////////////////////////
function spiro(R, r, O, tRatio, resolution, position) {

  var cx = canvas.width / 2;
  var cy = canvas.height / 2;
  position.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  var ox = cx;
  var oy = cy;

  var i = 0;
  var myIdent = ++ident;
  position.strokeStyle = "#000";

  function step() {
    if (ident != myIdent) return;

    position.beginPath();
    position.moveTo(ox, oy);


    let t = tRatio * i;
    let x = cx + ((R + r) * Math.cos(t) - (r + O) * Math.cos(((R + r) / r) * t));
    let y = cy - ((R + r) * Math.sin(t) - (r + O) * Math.sin(((R + r) / r) * t));

    ox = x;
    oy = y;
    position.lineTo(x, y);
    position.stroke();
    i++;
    if (i < 500) window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }

  step();

}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Draw spirograph
function drawSpiro(R, r, O, tRatio, i, position) {

  var cx = canvas.width / 2;
  var cy = canvas.height / 2;
  position.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  position.moveTo(cx, cy);
  position.beginPath();

  for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {

    let t = tRatio * i;
    let x = cx + ((R + r) * Math.cos(t) - (r + O) * Math.cos(((R + r) / r) * t));
    let y = cy - ((R + r) * Math.sin(t) - (r + O) * Math.sin(((R + r) / r) * t));

    position.lineTo(x, y);
    position.strokeStyle = "#000";
    position.stroke();
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid black;">

<script src="test.js"></script>

Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
<br>
<button onclick="draw(context)">Draw</button>
<button onclick="randoSpiro(context)">Random</button>
<button onlick="drawSpiro()">Draw Spiro</button>
<b>High = .01 </b> <input id="resolution" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" onchange="draw(context)"><b> 1 = Low</b>
<br> R
<input id="R" value="50" type="number" onchange="draw(context)"></td>
<br> r
<input id="r" value="75" type="number" onchange="draw(context)"></td>
<br> O
<input id="O" value="30" type="number" onchange="draw(context)"></td>
<br> T-Ratio
<input id="t" value="0.1" type="number" step="0.1" onchange="draw(context)">
<br>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help I was too busy trying to make a for loop hoping it did it one step at a time